# Tight coupling in using call back method

Tags: java, android

I am using below code and for result i am using interface for call back purposes.

```
@Override
public void onResult(String result) {

    if (this.mClient != null) {
        this.mClient.cancel();
        mProcessing = false;
    }

    try {
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject j1 = j.getJSONObject("status");
        int j2 = j1.getInt("code");
        if (j2 == 0) {
            JSONObject metadata = j.getJSONObject("metadata");
            //
            if (metadata.has("humming")) {
                JSONArray hummings = metadata.getJSONArray("humming");
                for (int i = 0; i < hummings.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) hummings.get(i);
                    String title = tt.getString("title");
                    JSONArray artistt = tt.getJSONArray("artists");
                    JSONObject art = (JSONObject) artistt.get(0);
                    String artist = art.getString("name");
                    tres = tres + (i + 1) + ".  Title: " + title + "    Artist: " + artist + "\n";
                }
            }
            if (metadata.has("music")) {
                JSONArray musics = metadata.getJSONArray("music");
                for (int i = 0; i < musics.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) musics.get(i);
                    String title = tt.getString("title");
                    JSONArray artistt = tt.getJSONArray("artists");
                    JSONObject art = (JSONObject) artistt.get(0);
                    String artist = art.getString("name");
                    tres = tres + (i + 1) + ".  Title: " + title + "    Artist: " + artist + "\n";
                }
            }
            if (metadata.has("streams")) {
                JSONArray musics = metadata.getJSONArray("streams");
                for (int i = 0; i < musics.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) musics.get(i);
                    String title = tt.getString("title");
                    JSONArray channelId = tt.getJSONArray("channel_id");
                    tres = tres + (i + 1) + ".  Title: " + title + "    Channel Id: " + channelId + "\n";
                }
            }
            if (metadata.has("custom_files")) {
                JSONArray musics = metadata.getJSONArray("custom_files");
                for (int i = 0; i < musics.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) musics.get(i);
                    String title = tt.getString("title");
                    //tres = tres + (i + 1) + ".  Title: " + title + "\n";
                    tres = tt.getString("acr_id");
                }
            }
            //tres = tres + "\n\n" + result;
            if (baseClass instanceof MainActivity)
                ((MainActivity) baseClass).onResultFound(tres);
        } else {
            tres = result;
            if (baseClass instanceof MainActivity)
                ((MainActivity) baseClass).onResultNotFound(tres);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        tres = result;
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (baseClass instanceof MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity) baseClass).onErrorFound(tres);
    }

    //mResult.setText(tres);

}
```

My question is that is it the right way of coding to give call back or it causes tight coupling issue using below code.

```
if (baseClass instanceof MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity) baseClass).onResultNotFound(tres);
```

Interface:

```
public interface IResultListener {

    /*
    * This is call back listener when acr starts recognition sound of audio/video
    * and methods are available according to result
    * */

    // result found successfully
    void onResultFound(String result);

    // result not found
    void onResultNotFound(String result);

    // some exception occurred
    void onErrorFound(String result);
}
```

Comment: You're not using interfaces at all - look up "java interface" and "implements interface"

Comment: I AM using interface. onResultFound, onResultNotFound are the methods belong to interface used in exception clause and if and else clause.As mentioned 'MainActivity' this is the class implementing my interface.

Comment: can you add the interface definition to your code in the question? And the `tres` and `baseClass` variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of casting to `MainActivity`, you should be casting to `IResultListener`.

```
if (baseClass instanceof IResultListener)
            ((IResultListener) baseClass).onResultNotFound(tres);
```

That said, usually one registers a listener. So you'd have a `List<IResultListener>` somewhere, and then in this method you'd call a method `fireEventResultFound(String result)`, which iterates over the list and calls `onResultFound` for each of them. This is called the Observer pattern (you can google that if you want to know more), and it decouples the reporting class from the observing class.

I also think you should move the parsing of `hummings` and `musics`, `streams` and `custom_files` to their own methods. That would greatly simplify this `onResult` method.

---

Also,

```
tres = tt.getString("acr_id");
```

Is this a possible bug? Everywhere else you're appending, but here you just overwrite the result.

Comment: No that is not a bug. I just want to get id on that case and in rest of the case I am parsing complete json.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed if it is not a bug, then at that point, you're done parsing and could stop the entire parse function

Comment: yes, you are right I am doing some extra work just for nothing. Thank you for mentioning that  :)